# More elegant and secure solution to passing object path references

Tags: javascript, object, message-passing

I've been reading SICP and one concept they teach is abstracting certain details away from the user. I'm trying to build a set of subfunctions that return object paths that can be passed as an argument in a higher order function.
The problem I found was that most of the time javascript will resolve the object path to whatever value it's referencing before passing it to the higher order function.
With some help I managed to cobble together this crude solution but I was hoping theres a better way.

```
let object = {
prop1: "sth",
prop2: "sthelse"
}
function getPath(whichProp) {
    return `object["${whichProp}"]`};

function deleteProp(aPath) {
    console.log(aPath) //prints object["prop1"]
    eval(`delete ${aPath}`);
    console.log(object) // {prop2: sthelse}
}

deleteProp(getPath("prop1"))
```

Is there some method of message passing that can be used here? Having the function resolve to a function calling it's argument with itself as that functions' argument.
Hope that's coherent, thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no built in way in JS, but it would be handy if there was.  But it's pretty trivial to role your own without using eval..  Or alternatively you could use a lib that does it eg. lodash has the get method.. -> https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#get

Comment: I would say pass the path as a list of keys and object reference instead of full code part. You could use recurssion to get/delete anything you want

Comment: The "new" way of programming javascript is to keep a separate data store that has functions for getting and retrieving data (such as Redux), or to create an "observable" data stream where you can listen for data changes (see for example ObservableHQ). If you want to research abstracting away data then that may be interesting for you? Using `eval` is very unsafe because unintended code may get executed. Sorry if this is a bit off-topic.